# Users who have role "SQLAgentReaderRole" don't see SQL Server Agent on SSMS

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

A user asked me to have permission to schedule jobs on Microsoft SQL Server Management because he doesn't see SQL Server Agent. I added the role SQLAgentReaderRole to the user but SQL Server Agent doesn't appear when he disconnected and reconnected.

I followed Microsoft guide (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/agent/configure-a-user-to-create-and-manage-sql-server-agent-jobs?view=sql-server-ver16) but it doesn't work.
I need to add sysadmin role to the user to SQL Server Agent be appeared

Comment: I can't replicate your problem. Simply refreshing the object explorer, after creating a `USER` for the `LOGIN` in `msdb` and giving them the `SQLAgentReaderRole` role caused the SQL Server Agent node to appear.

Comment: This is what I done for the first time but SQL Server Agent not appeared for the user. So I created a test user and give SQLAgentReaderRole to my test user. I refreshed object explorer but couldn't see SQL Server Agent node.

Comment: To add information. I tried the same procedure on another SQL Server and SQL Server Agent appeared witout problem. The only difference is the version of SQL Server. The server on which I have this problem is 2016 and the other server is 2019.